# Product Gallery in Drupal 7 (like Amazon's)

Tags: drupal-7, image-gallery, galleryview

I want to create a product preview gallery page for a certain node type. I do not want to use any eCommerce plugin nor do I want to use Drupal's Kick Starter. I simply want to replicate the image thumbnail hover/gallery in Amazon's inner product pages. Is there a way you can do this in a simpler approach? A simple plugin will do, but it would be best if it can be done even simpler just by using Drupal 7's defaults.

Comment: Welcome at SO. You have a good question, but it is best to include some code you already have. If this is not code related, maybe try another StackExchange site such as http://webapps.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a gallery with drupal views and views slideshow.
check this page out
https://drupal.org/node/1497058

Also it would helpful if you could provide a link to the page you are referring to in amazon to get a better idea.

Comment: I want to replicate this kind of image hover/preview: http://www.amazon.com/Rosewill-Aluminum-Enclosure-RX35-AT-SU-SLV/dp/B004ASY5ZY/ref=sr_1_cc_1?s=aps&ie=UTF8&qid=1390916862&sr=1-1-catcorr&keywords=3.5+hdd+enclosure+rosewill

Comment: Yes it will work that way. download drupal views and drupal viewsslide show. Create a view in a page. select the content type and its fields. You can set format as slideshow and there is an option to use a pager. Here you can change settings of that pager to allow the image to change on hover. This will work.

Comment: There is a built-in preview on hover for views slideshow? Just to clarify. :)

Comment: Yes when you hover on a thumbnail image the the main image changes.. If thats what you meant

Comment: What I have right now is a field containing four uploaded images named `field_product_images`. I am trying to display this on Views using the Slideshow format. Unfortunately, as I understand it, the slideshow considers one field per slide. Is that correct? I want to make a gallery for the single field I'm using that contains four images.

How about in that case?